# Paging MySQL DB result

Tags: java, mysql, spring, pagination

I am having 50000 entries in MySQL DB, which need to be fetches and iterated in java. Is it required to do pagination ?

This table could contain 20 columns which are varchar(100).

If its not possible, Is pagination required if I am fetching only 1 column from each row for these 50000 entries ?

Comment: Just try it. Depends on how you fetch them, server performance and so on. Displaying 50k elements also takes some time to render in a table in Java.

Comment: You might want to tune the fetch size to keep the memory usage efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on your use case. If you want to display it to an end user you will very likely need pagination as displaying this much data in one go may make your UI sluggish (apart from not being very user-friendly). If you just need to do calculations in a background task, you can probably live without pagination.